# Read length prefix before deserialize with length prefix

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Is there any way in protobuf-net to read packet length from stream and after that deserialize the packet using `Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix`? I mean to do these operations without copying data to additional streams etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends a lot on what you mean by "read packet length from stream". Firstly, *packets* **do not exist** in a stream - you just have: the stream. You can *frame* inside that, and this is precisely what the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods *already do*. So if you use the `*WithLengthPrefix` methods at both ends, it should already read correctly without attempting to over-read etc. However, there is not enough information in the question to say much more than this.

---

From the clarification in the comments; yes, you could use `Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix` to read the prefix *manually* - and then create a length-limited reader; if it was synchronous code something like:

```
while(Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix(stream, style, out length))
{
    using(var reader = new ProtoReader(stream, model, ctx, length))
    {
        var obj = mode.Deserialize(reader, null, type);
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, in async IO the code gets *much* more complex; first you need to buffer until you know you have enough for the frame header; then you need to continue reading and buffering until you have the data for the frame. Your basic async loop will be much more like:

```
EndRead() {
    AppendNewData();
    bool consumed = false;
    while(HaveFrameHeaderInBuffer() && HavePayloadInBuffer()) {
        ProcessFrame();
        consumed = true;
    }
    if(consumed) DiscardConsumedDataAndShiftLeftoverUnusedData();
    BeginRead();
}
```

Comment: What exactly I need to do is to deserialize object (with some extensions) from the stream (that is why I use *WithLengthPrefix methods) and at the same time get its byte-length for a kind of network statistics purpose. But I can't just read first bytes from the stream to get object's length because after that I can't return stream position back for deserializing. Ideally, method DeserializeWithLengthPrefix can return serialized object length. But because it does not I'm looking for an alternative way.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm reading from a BinaryReader stream, and want to time slice the serialization process using yield return. How can I do that?

Comment: @bartburkhardt it is  unclear to me  *why* you would use `BinaryReader`... it isn't appropriate here (note that streams are, fundamentally, devices capable of binary read - `BinaryReader` is just a  utility wrapper that can assist with some type conversions, but that doesn't apply if your data format isn't the one that `BinaryReader` wants). Can you clarify what you mean by "want to time slice the serialization process" ?

Comment: I use it in Unity3d. To keep smooth animation I now read a file in the game loop using yield return. So if the game runs 60fps, the file is loaded in portions to have smooth animation. I switched from binary formatter to Protobuf which is 4 times faster in serializing, but there is still a hickup in the game when I load a file object of 1.7mb

Comment: @bartburkhardt k ... so are you saying that what you want to do is deserialize *some amount* each slice? Is this one big object? or is it a collection of sub-objects? (or could it be interpreted as such). What you describe is probably achievable, but is quite complex and demands more context.

Comment: Yes, I would like to deserialize some amount each slice. Its one object with some large lists of objects

Comment: @bartburkhardt it takes a little bit of hackery - you basically need to rewrite the serializer code for the outermost type; but you can do it - is this useful at all? http://pastie.org/10198243

Comment: Is there a way one could use Serializer.TryReadLengthPrefix to read the prefix manually and then create a length-limited reader nowadays?  ProtoReader doesn't seem to work this way anymore.

Comment: @Michael it should work the same still; there is a slight API change to prefer the state reader in V3, but that's just moving to .Create

Comment: @MarcGravell, when I try to use ProtoReader as in the example above, I get an error: CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'ProtoReader'

Comment: "but that's just moving to .Create" - specifically, `ProtoReader.Create` (which does what the constructor used to do, but is now marked obsolete), or `ProtoReader.State.Create` (which is a ref-struct API). There may be other options, too, however; if you have the data in-memory (`byte[]`, `MemoryStream`, etc) - you can *slice* that buffer and use that as a `ReadOnlyMemory<byte>` / `ReadOnlySpan<byte>`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you.  I understand now and this works perfectly.